# In Qt; what is the best method to capitalise the first letter of every word in a QString?

Tags: c++, regex, string, qt, qstring

I am thinking of regular expressions, but that is not exactly readable. There are also functions like `s.toUpper()` to consider, and probably other things as well.

So what is the best method for capitalising the first letter of words in a QString?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Most efficient, most readable, most maintainable? There isn't a great deal of information here. Do you have 1000 `QString` that you want to handle, or are you just starting?

Comment: I can't see any better method than iterating over the string and capitalizing every letter after a space.

Comment: Yes any sort of loop you like I guess which lets you get at the characters. I don't know a bean about QT but i'd think a range based for loop would be best choice for the sake of brevity.

Comment: See [this example](https://wiki.qt.io/Converting_Strings_from_and_to_Camel_Case).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [this example](https://wiki.qt.io/Converting_Strings_from_and_to_Camel_Case) as a reference, you can do something like this:

```
QString toCamelCase(const QString& s)
{
    QStringList parts = s.split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); ++i)
        parts[i].replace(0, 1, parts[i][0].toUpper());

    return parts.join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same, but written differently :

```
QString toCamelCase(const QString& s)
{
    QStringList cased;
        foreach (QString word, s.split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts))cased << word.at(0).toUpper() + word.mid(1);

    return cased.join(" ");
}
```

This uses more memory but is without pointer access (no brackets operator).

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative way of doing this which iterates using references to the words and modifies the first character using a QChar reference instead:

```c++
QString capitalise_each_word(const QString& sentence)
{
  QStringList words = sentence.split(" ", Qt::SkipEmptyParts);
  for (QString& word : words)
    word.front() = word.front().toUpper();

  return words.join(" ");
}
```

Note that `Qt::SkipEmptyParts` is required here (as in the other answers to this question) since the first character of each word is assumed to exist when capitalising. This assumption will not hold with `Qt::KeepEmptyParts` (the default).

Answer (score 0):

If the `QString` is placed in any item that uses `QFont`, you can use its `setCapitalization` property to change text to title case. Here is an example - my code is very happy to have discovered it.

```
QFont formatFont = m_formatNameEdit->font();
formatFont.setCapitalization(QFont::Capitalize);
m_formatNameEdit->setFont(formatFont);
```

Thanks to an answer from [Qt Centre Thread: How to capitalize a string](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32523-How-to-capitalize-a-string)

Answer (score -2):

Incredible C++/Qt... You just want to get some chars ored with 0x20...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah, sure, always work to make an ASCII "upcase", when the string can be Unicode, UTF-8, non-latin, etc.